# An example of function that is defined everywhere but is not the derivative of any differentiable function.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, examples-counterexamples, differential

Can someone give me an example of such a function?

Comment: $H(x)=0$ for $x\lt0$, $H(x)=1$ for $x\ge0$.

Comment: @kingW3 That's not so.  There are differentiable functions with discontinuous derivatives.

Comment: @kingW3 that's not true. If you said "any function with a jump-discontinuity" then it would be true.

Comment: @bof $H(x)=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}[xH(x)]$ on $\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$.

Comment: @Sandejo Indeed, a big part of $H$ is a derivative. But the whole $H$ isn't.